# How do I identify which query failed in php mysqli transaction with try catch finally

Tags: php, mysqli, transactions, try-catch

How can I identify which query caused a rollback when executing multiple prepared queries in a PHP MySQL transaction? I'd like to do this to provide a meaningful message, via email, to a particular person so would prefer not to simply send the exception response.

I believe the code snippet below (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603619/how-to-write-transaction-for-2-prepared-statement-to-ensure-commit-or-rollback)) using an update and an insert as examples will execute the two queries or roll back both of them. But is there a way, in this simple example, to put two echo statements in the catch block that will show a different message depending upon which query, the update or the insert, failed?

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);  //connect to database
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {      // Check connection
    log_message("Failed to connect to MySQL  " . mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
try { //finally
    $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE table1 SET f1 = 1 WHERE f2 = ? AND f3 = ?");
    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table2 (f4,f5) VALUES (?,?)");
    $conn->begin_transaction();
    try {  // catch
        $stmt1->bind_param('iii', $data1, $data2, $data3); //bind parameters to update query
        $stmt1->execute();                               //execute update
        $stmt2->bind_param('ii', $data4, $data5);         //bind parameters to insert query
        $stmt2->execute();                               //execute insert
        $conn->commit();                                 //no errors, commit both queries
    } //end try catch
    catch (Exception $e) {                               //something went wrong
        $conn->rollback();
        echo "SQL error ".$e->getMessage();              //report error - but which query failed?
    }
}//try finally
finally {
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

*Note: The code above is a modified version of my real code (which is rather more complex) just to illustrate the point for this question and to show the general structure of my real code. If you spot a syntax error in it then please feel free to edit it rather than leave a comment telling me it won't run as it is or that it's not my real code*.

Comment: You really should remove the `finally` block. It doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: This code `if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {` will never work and can be removed. If you are using exceptions then the exception would stop the code before this `if`.

Comment: The `if (mysqli_connect_errno()) ` is used in case a connection cannot be made using the parameters provided, not in the case of an exception. Sometimes the server is down so I need to log that. The connection is not inside a try catch block.

Comment: The finally block is there to make sure I close the connection in that section of code. Later parts of the code rely on the connection being closed, whether there was an exception or not

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to wrap it in a function? If the variable is in a local scope, you know it will be closed when you leave the scope.

Comment: When the connection fails you will get an exception. If you want to handle that, you need a try-catch. If you have mysqli errors silenced then your transaction will never work properly.

Comment: It is within a function but there is stuff later in the function that requires the connection closed (before leaving that function). Anyway I would rather explicitly close the connection than use scope rules to do it for me. Makes the code much easier to follow. I'm not a fan of source code optimisation i.e. sacrificing readability for the sake of reducing a few key strokes.

Comment: I think you need more consistent approach at error reporting. Right now it's a motley bunch that uses built-in error reporting here and manual error checking there, prints errors here and logs them there. Let me suggest you an article I wrote, [PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting). Note that PHP is pretty capable of logging errors for you ;) and besides, just like Dharman says, either mysqli_connect_errno() will never return false or your transactions will **never trigger catch and rollback**. You shouldn't brush this information off. It's vital for your app

Answer (score 0):

The exception you catch will contain the file's name and the line on which the exception happened. Using this information you can figure out which statement failed.

The exception you get from mysqli doesn't contain the SQL query used because the exception could have been thrown for many different reasons. It doesn't have to be the fault of the SQL at all. Your transaction could roll back for issues unrelated to SQL. So, there is no way to determine which SQL was at fault.

But this is ok. If you want to inform the developer of an issue, you can just send them the exception together with the full backtrace. They can look at the code and find the line number from which the exception occurred. There is no need to send this information to anyone who is not a developer. If you are thinking of sending this to the database administrator, then it would be wrong. First the developer should investigate the exception as it's most likely an issue in the code. If they decide it's an issue with the database then the developer should forward the incident to the relevant person. However, the code should inform only the developer of the issue.